# Can Azure Data Factory V2 copy files that are updated every 20 seconds from on-premises to Azure Data Lake as soon as they change

Tags: azure-data-factory

I am trying to use ADF V2 to copy real time data from on-premises to Azure Data Lake Store.  I already installed a self-hosted Integration Runtime on the on-premises server.  Then I used the Copy Data wizard to create the pipeline and the datasets.

I tried using a tumbling window trigger to fire as soon the file changes, but saw that the minimum time it will fire is 15 minutes.

I saw that there is a Get Metadata activity that can get the Last Modified Time on a file system file.  And I see that the Dataset allows parameters to be added.  However, in V2 I see no Help button or examples on that.  So I am assuming I would have to change the JSON file.

However, before I do that: the question is

> > can the pipeline be triggered - every 2 or 3 seconds (continuously) - to check if the files have changed and then copy them to Azure Data Lake store?

If that is possible, any example(s) would be really helpful.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

What is your source on the on-premise server? You can use a combination of logic app and ADF to, so logic app can be triggered as soon as file arrives at your on-premise source side, and then the logic app can invoke data factory pipeline to copy that file.

Comment: The source - on-premise - is a Windows file share where log files get data appended to them (every few seconds) or new log files added (every few seconds).

Comment: Do Logic apps have built in connectors for Windows file share and for invoking ADF?  Thanks

Comment: you should check this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-using-file-connector